# Cannot parse topic - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

My script was running fine few hours back and when i run it now i am getting the following  error from my node script...

```
Error: Cannot parse topic
    at Parser._parsePublish (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt-packet/parser.js:242:53)
    at Parser._parsePayload (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt-packet/parser.js:104:14)
    at Parser.parse (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt-packet/parser.js:37:48)
    at Writable.writable._write (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:258:12)
    at doWrite (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:406:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:395:5)
    at Writable.write (/home/ubuntu/we2/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:322:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:557:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

the script is listening to a mosquitto broker using mqtt.js.

PS: No updates or changes has been made to the code. Mosquitto broker is running fine and connecting to test client.

thanks.

code:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
            moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();

            //mqtt initialize
            const mqtt = require('mqtt')
            const client = mqtt.connect('----', {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            });


            //influx initalisation
            var influx = require('influx')
            var username = 'root'
            var password = 'root'
            var database = '---'

            //db details
            GLOBAL.dat = [];
            var client_db = influx({host: 'localhost', username: username, password: password, database: database})

            //redis initialisation
            var redis = require('redis');
            var redisClient = redis.createClient({host: 'localhost', port: 6379});
            var sub = redis.createClient(), pub = redis.createClient();

            //general declarations
            var msg_count = 0;
            var gateID = "";


            sub.on("subscribe", function (channel, count) {

                console.log('info', 'IPC Communication Initiated on channel: ' + channel)

            });

            sub.on("message", function (channel, message) {
                console.log('info', 'IPC Communication Buffer %s', message)
            });


            //mqtt client
            client.on('connect', function () {

                client.subscribe('Topic/#')
                console.log('info', 'Subscribing to topic %s', "FlowData")


            })

            client.on('message', function (topic, message) {

                console.log("topic is " + topic.toString());
                console.log("message is " + message.toString());

            //removethis later
                var chk = (topic.toString()).substr(0, 2);
                var chkFlow = (topic.toString()).substr(12, 2);


                if (chk == "Fl") {
                    console.log('info', "FHandler Inititated");


                    var messSplit = String(message).split("/");
                    gateID = String(messSplit[0]);
                    var compID = String(messSplit[1]);
                    var temp = String(messSplit[2]).split(":");
                    var compTime = String(temp[1]);
                    var compValue = parseInt(temp[0]);


                    redisPrevData(compID, function (response) {

                        if (typeof response !== "object") {

                            console.log(response);


                        }
                        else {
                            prevCompValue == 'NDF';
                            core(compID, compValue, function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                        }

                    });



                    client_db.writePoint(gateID.toString(), {value: compValue}, {compID: compID.toString()}, {time: compTime}, function (e, response) {
                       if (e) throw e
                    })
                    console.log('info', "Written data to TimeSeries");
                    currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");


                    console.log('info', "IPC Send Data to other handlers");
                    console.log('info', "FHandler Completed");


                }


            })


            function redisPrevData(compID, callback) {
                vardummy = apartID + currentDate;
                console.log(vardummy);
                redisClient.getAsync(vardummy).then(function (res) {
                    console.log("redis : " + res);
                    return callback(res);
                });


            }


            function core(compID, value) {
                if (prevCompValue == 'NDF') {

                    redisClient.set(compID, value, redisClient.print);
                    return callback("New comp init - written to redis");

                }
                else {

                    if (compValue < prevCompValue) {
                        //alarm to trigger - ignore the data log it seprately.
                        return callback("ALARM TRIGGER ILLEGAL VALUES");
                    }
                    else if (compValue >= prevCompValue) {
                        //update in influx
                        return callback("Normal - writing to influx");
                    }


                }


            }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki added. thanks

Comment: Are you using retained messages? What happens if you use the `mosquitto_sub -t "Topic/#"` command to subscribe to the same messages?

Comment: @hardillb : mosquitto_sub -t "Topic/#"
Error: A network protocol error occurred when communicating with the broker

it throws an error ...

Comment: This might imply that there is issue with a queued message. Try restarting your broker (and possibly deleting the persistence file)

Comment: @hardillb Thanks a Ton! . Restarting Worked.!